# Allow optional unlimited spaces and hyphens in a regular expression that uses a quantifier

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate either a visa or mastercard regular number using a regular expression and have come up with this:

```
^(4[0-9]{12}([A-Z]?)(?:[0-9]{3})?)|(5[1-5][0-9]{14})$
```

I am unsure of how to allow any number of hyphens or dashes, whilst still enforcing the pattern.

Comment: A common advice here is to remove any non-numeric chars from the string and apply regex to that clean string. Or, you will have to add `[\s-]?` or `[\s-]*` at every place where you allow it to appear.

Comment: True, but this is to validate using js on the client side and I find it annoying when I type something into an input and it is stripped out automatically.

Comment: In JS, you may easily use `/your-regex/.test(s.replace(/\W+/g,''))`. Just noticed that your regex contains a mistake, use `^(?:(4[0-9]{12}([A-Z]?)(?:[0-9]{3})?)|(5[1-5][0-9]{14}))$`

Comment: thanks, is this possible without the replace? Im using unobtrusive validation so ideally dont want to have to use custom code. Is it going to really complicate the regex to use your first suggestion?

Comment: What is complicated is highly subjective, and on SO, this subjectivity is quadrupled (people downovte or upvote lots of questions or answers for nothing sometimes). It is possible. See https://regex101.com/r/IIBioR/1

Comment: ok thankyou Wiktor

Comment: Here is [my try](https://regex101.com/r/IIBioR/1), no idea it will be working for you since you did not post exact requirements. Space or hyphens, but how many? Can there be leading/trailing spaces/hyphens?

Comment: basically i want to enforce the above pattern, but allow any number of spaces and hyphens that the user may add. I dont want to be strict if there are mulitple or they appear at the start end or in between. I will strip them out myself on the server.

Comment: Then replace all `?` with `*`. And add `[\s-]*` at  the start/end of the pattern (after `^` and before `$`)

Comment: Ah, my pattern contained an issue - [see an update here](https://regex101.com/r/IIBioR/2).

Comment: awesome, thanks again. Nice regex testing site, I haven't used that before

Comment: I posted and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach that is used by the majority of users is to remove all non-word chars before applying the regex with `[\W_]+` pattern (1 or more non-word chars and/or `_`). You will only have digits and letters to match.

However, your current pattern does not really do what you expect as the two alterantives are anchored independently at the start (the first one) and the end (the second one). You may fix it using

```
^(4[0-9]{12}([A-Z]?)(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14})$
```

If you have some specific requirement to cram all into 1 regex, you may consider

```
^[\s-]*(?:4(?:[-\s]*[0-9]){12}([-\s]*[A-Z])?(?:(?:[-\s]*[0-9]){3})?|5[-\s]*[1-5](?:[-\s]*[0-9]){14})[\s-]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIBioR/2).

Any number of leading/trailing whitespaces and/or hyphens (and anywhere in between valid patterns) can be input.

The point is to quantify a group, not the digit pattern. `(?:[-\s]*[0-9]){12}` matches 12 consecutive sequences of 0+ occurrences of `-` or whitespace followed with a single digit. So, between each of the 12 digits there can be a space, newline, other whitespace and `-`.